# FlashForge Adventurer 3 cooling fan making grinding sound

Tags: print-fan, flashforge-adventurer-3

Ever since I got this printer for my 15th birthday the cooling fan has made a grinding sound when the nozzle was near the wall. I thought it was just the clear wall vibrating but now when I start a print it makes the sound all the time and it's getting really annoying. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

I got a used Artillery Hornet back in December 2022 and whenever it began heating up the nozzle it would make noises like those of a jet engine. It was crazy. It needed some maintenance.

***Important:** Please **unplug your printer** before cleaning it. It "being off" isn't enough. Safety first at all times.*

What I did was check every fan the printer has, so the ones on the carriage (in the hornet I had three next to the heating block) but also in the power source, and make sure they were completely clean from dust bunnies/cat hair/anything else. You'll see how it accumulates on the edge of the blades. You can collect the fluff with tweezers, then use a cotton swab with isopropyl alcohol in case there's some stubborn dirt left you need to gently scrub off.

Afterwards I added a tiny droplet of graphite grease on the little hole they have on the back; sometimes it's covered with a sticker, in that case peel it off to access said hole. Don't go overboard of course, just a tiny drop is enough. Spin it a little to make sure the lubricant is spread evenly.

Reassemble everything, plug the printer and try heating up the nozzle again to check for results.

I would try this before checking for more involved things like software issues. You'd be surprised at how much of a difference the regular cleaning and lubrication of your printer makes.

Comment: thx I will try that but will WD40 work or grease

Comment: WD40 is more for getting mechanical parts unstuck. I always use graphite grease. It comes in a can like WD40 but it's a bit thicker and also silver colored. It's the best lubricant for moving parts there is.

Comment: I mean what else could i use I dont have graphite grease i have my 3d printer provided grease

Comment: You can buy graphite greas at any hardware store. It comes in a can like WD40. You can use WD40 but that's not really a lubrican, it's for unsticking mechanical parts or displacing moisture.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, check your fan. There might be something stuck inside. You can clean it with a soft toothbrush. Take a look at the fan blades as well. Sometimes they can get bent. If the fan is spinning at a high speed, you can check the area where it's mounted. It may not be securely in place. Also, these kinds of issues can sometimes be software- related. Make sure to update your printer with any available updates.

Comment: It's not dusty it's enclosed and there is nothing stuck in it the blades are fine it is secured in place and I just updated it. do you have any other ideas?